# Visual Studio debugger highlights multiple lines instead of just the current line

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

Weird one here,

My fresh install of Visual Studio 2017 (Version 15.6.7) is showing multiple lines in yellow when I try to step-through debug, like so:

[image]

It seems to be pointing to the correct line that it's on, but also several others below it. Maybe it's something to do with indentation, or scope, I'm not sure. But it's a little misleading to myself and other devs when I do paired-programming.

I've tried Googling this issue and have found nothing, and I've looked at the text formatting in VS settings myself to see if anything has accidentally been enabled that might cause this. But still nothing.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: If possible, you could share us the sample using one drive, so we could really debug it in our side using the same Environment, I met this kind of issue before which was related to the LAMBDA EXPRESSIONS in the project code.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't share source. It's with a company project, otherwise I would. I will experiment a bit more, re: lambda expressions, and get back to you.

Comment: What about this issue? Would you please share the latest information in your side?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT the issue has stopped occurring. I am not sure why. I haven't updated Visual Studio, so perhaps it was related to my build somehow?

Comment: Glad to know that it works well now. Of course, if you get the detailed solution or useful steps in your side,  you could share it as the answer, so it could help other community members. Have a nice day:)

Comment: I got the same problem and it didnt fix itself after a pc restart. I have no idea how to fix this