# Visual Studio 2019 with multiple debug yellow lines

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019

I'm having a problem in my Visual Studio Community 2019.

When debugging the project, when you stop on the breakpoints, the yellow line indicative of stop, it does not only highlight the line in which you have the breakpoint, but several lines are highlighted being below the point where the breakpoint is.

As you progress with F10, that amount of lines changes, which can be more or less ... especially when entering into ifs or loops, it gets worse if you follow the debug.

I have cleaned bin and obj folders, rebuild several times, I entered the properties of the solution and cleared the build options and redialed, I did many approaches in order to regularize the operation, but nothing worked.

Detail is that this project was created in Visual Studio 2017 and there does not have this problem. It just happens in Visual Studio 2019.

I have the last update installed, 16.1.4.

My project is Xamarin.Forms 3.6 and in the case in question, I am debugging directly to an Android device.

What I want is to just leave the current course line highlighted, not this lot of yellow lines, which greatly confounds the follow-up of the debugging process.

Thank you.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

To fix the issue I set the following Android project option: 
Android Options -> Linking -> NONE

Answer (score 0):

> According to the debugger works well in VS2017 but not VS2019:

1.Maybe something in your current setting which causes this issue, you can go `Tools=>Import and Export Settings` to reset all settings with `overwrite my current settings option`. (Before that you can use `export environment settings` to backup it)

2.You can navigate to your Solution folder, close all VS instances and then delete the `.vs` folder, `bin and obj` folder manually under project directory to check if it helps.Sometimes the content in .vs from VS2017 will cause some issue after migrating to VS2019.

3.Not sure if your code is optimized for debug mode. Go Debug menu=>Enable Suppress JIT optimization on module load and rebuild the project to check if it makes some difference.(If this is the cause,maybe you've enabled the Optimize Code in Project=>Properties=>Build)

4.Also it look similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464143/visual-studio-debugger-highlights-multiple-lines-instead-of-just-the-current-lin),so you can check if this issue persists after the restart of PC. Then you can create a new project and add some simple code to make the similar structure to check if this issue goes away.